# Set enable=true to a UITextField with gesture recognizer

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uigesturerecognizer

I have a ***UITextField*** not editable (the property .enabled is false).
I want to make the textfield editable with a ***UILongPressGestureRecognizer***.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not, although you might have to put the recognizer on the container instead.  `enabled` doesn't explicitly say whether or not it affects `userInteractionEnabled` but implies that it might.  If it does you'll need to put it on the container, if it doesn't then you can put it on the text field itself.

Of course, the short answer is:

"Try it and see"